# How to use scss files from NuGet package in Blazor?

Tags: sass, nuget, blazor

I have a nuget package that contains as static web assets a series of css and scss files, when I reference css files using _content/packageName/file.css I have no problem but when I try to do the same with an scss (_content/packageName/file.scss) file it doesn't find it. I need to use variables from mi nuget scss files, is there a way to access them without having to add source code to my project?

Comment: I don't think so.  Libraries are fixed - you can't "re-compile" them.  I pretty sure that applies to the CSS.  If you want to rebuild the CSS you need to get your hands on the source scss and then reference the recompiled css files.

Answer (score 1):

Quoting [CSS isolation bundling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/css-isolation?view=aspnetcore-5.0#css-isolation-bundling):

> CSS isolation occurs at build time. During this process, Blazor rewrites CSS selectors to match markup rendered by the component. These rewritten CSS styles are bundled and produced as a static asset at {PROJECT NAME}.styles.css, where the placeholder {PROJECT NAME} is the referenced package or product name.

```
<link href="ProjectName.styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
```